# Managing Different User Roles ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authorization, user-roles

I am currently developing a ASP.NET MVC4 website, and I would like to know whats the best practices storing the logged-on user's data (include privileges) and authorize the user securely, being able to access this data in both my views and controllers.

One thing to important mention - I am **NOT using the Membership class** (I've saw that its an overhead for me to use it, and I would like to implement the exact things I need and learn from the process).

The only way I thought to do it is storing all the data inside the session object, and having a wrapper to the session object (static class) and use it like `SessionManager.IsLoggedIn()`, `SessionManager.GetUserPriviliges()` or simply creating a method that returns hard-typed UserSessionData `SessionManager.GetSessionData()` that contains all the data required. 
This is one way to use it in both controllers and views. Shall I derive from Controller and create a `RolesController` which stores UserSessionData so I won't need to call it again and again in my controllers?

I guess I won't be able to use the common `AuthorizedAttribute` so I will have to implement it by using the session wrapper (Is it safe to use only the session data? since I am not using the 'official' authorization method and therefore I don't really know how it should be implemented).

As you see, I have an idea but since its my first time doing it I would like to learn about the best practices and the way it should be done correctly. I will be thankful if you will explain your answers since I want to get the complete idea and I haven't done it before in MVC.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Best practices" is an inherently subjective thing. Person #1 may say that 'Best Practice' is to use the Membership model. I know that under normal circumstances, I'd say that.  Don't reinvent the wheel.  I also know that some places had a membership system before .NET, and you have to work within its confines, since it doesn't pay to re do the work.  My point is, there's no canonical answer to this question. The answer is (and always will be) **it depends**.  The QA format isn't so good at answering those kinds of questions. Best of luck in your efforts.

Answer (score 3):

It is not safe to do anything you've described.  Static classis are dangerous in asp.net because they are not multi-user safe.  Static classes are shared between all threads in the app, including threads running other users requests.

Just use the default mamebership until you know what you're doing.  You will just be creating a vulnerable architecture otherwise.